# Calling a Method that uses an Intent Crashes the App

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a view in my XML that references a method that in turn is *supposed to* open the AnnouncementsScreen.java class, but it throws the following logcat message. It seems to state that it cannot find the AnnouncementsScreen.java file, although it's been declared in the manifest, and I've triple checked the spelling.

```
11-09 23:05:22.040 28199-28199/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
11-09 23:05:22.040 28199-28199/? E/Zygote: v2
11-09 23:05:22.060 28199-28199/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.t99sdevelopment.centralized, PID: 28199
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(SupportMenuInflater.java:259)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:300)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(SupportMenuInflater.java:255)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:300) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized.AnnouncementsScreen}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1499)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3913)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3860)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4184)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4152)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.t99sdevelopment.centralized.HomeScreen.goToAnnouncements(HomeScreen.java:37)
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(SupportMenuInflater.java:255) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:300) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
11-09 23:05:26.090 28199-28199/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

If anyone wants to fact check me on the files, the entire GitHub project is [here](https://github.com/T99-/Centralized). I can't find anything on the other exceptions that was meaningful to me, so I started here, but if anyone understands the other errs and can explain them, that'd be great.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.t99sdevelopment.centralized" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AnnouncementsScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_announcements_screen"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeScreen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
             >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.t99sdevelopment.centralized.HomeScreen" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ScheduleScreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CalendarScreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ContactBookScreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SportsScheduleScreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FrontAndCentralScreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapScreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AccountScreen" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the Activity where the error is occurring:

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent intentAnnouncements = new Intent(this, AnnouncementsScreen.class);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homescreen);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    }


    public void goToAnnouncements(MenuItem item){ startActivity(intentAnnouncements); }

}
```

**EDIT:**

The error was pointed out by @njzk2. I could not use the *this* keyword before the class had been fully initialized. I moved the declaration of the intent into its respective method, and it works just fine now. The issue had nothing to do with my Android manifest, but rather the reference to the HomeScreen.class by the *this( keyword.

Comment: I don't think you can create the intent at this point, since the activity is not yet created, and the context is not fully initialized. Try to create your intent only when you actually use it.

Comment: did you try removing the meta data inside?

Comment: I think @njzk2 nailed it.

Comment: Hey, please check your package name, I think it's wrong

Comment: @njzk2 This is my first app, and I added a navigation drawer, so I'm trying to test both that and my knowledge of intents at the same time. So, as a genuine question, why could I not create it yet?

Comment: @TrevorSears you can't use `this` as a Context before the Activity is fully initialized, as it is null when you're using it to set up the Intent.

Answer (score 0):

you did a small mistake,

```
<activity
            android:name=".AnnouncementsScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_announcements_screen"
            android:parentActivityName=".HomeScreen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

In your manifest file, you have declared the above class named **.AnnouncementsScreen** and you are asking into your question that,

> It seems to state that it cannot find the **AnnouncementScreen.java** file.

So, both the classes are different, so just replace your activity name from **.AnnouncementsScreen** to **.AnnouncementScreen**, it works for you.

Comment: It was just a typo in the question, here is the file: https://github.com/T99-/Centralized/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/t99sdevelopment/centralized/AnnouncementsScreen.java

Comment: let me import this and will get back to you soon.

Comment: Hey, as I have checked your code, I think you are using eclipse, instead you can import this project in Android Studio, it works.

Answer (score -2):

It is because of java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException first validate your target class in your manifest file.

`<activity
  android:name=".Target"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_target" >
</activity>`

Hope it will work..

Comment: [I already created the reference in my manifest.](https://github.com/T99-/Centralized/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: check your syntax of activity name

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT 2**

I have download this code and run

Just change function goToAnnouncements:

```
public void goToAnnouncements(MenuItem item){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnnouncementsScreen.class);

    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Please update your code

**EDIT**

Could you please add code about this class appear error ?

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.t99sdevelopment.centralized.AnnouncementsScreen}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Check your error log! Please add declared all activity to AndroidManifest.xml before running app

```
<activity
    android:name="com.t99sdevelopment.centralized.AnnouncementsScreen"/>
```

Comment: [I did already](https://github.com/T99-/Centralized/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml), that's why the error is confusing me.